Does a block's velocity becomes zero when it hits a spring?


It says the velocity of the block becomes zero at the instant of maximum compression. But does it not go with a constant velocity as it's a smooth part? It should hit the spring and then oscillate for a bit right? So how does it become zero?
I keep getting doubts related to when and why the velocity becomes zero in different cases... Are there certain conditions in which velocity will definitely become zero?

oscillations in 1D imply that at some points the instantaneous velocity is zero. It is very obvious that the question is asking you to consider those points.

In ideal case, the block's PE becomes fully KE at the bottom which again becomes fully potential of spring.

So the fact that potential kinetic energy of block becomes completely converted into potential energy of spring means that the velocity of block be 0 at maximum compression otherwise there will be some potential and some kinetic energy.

In classical mechanics, velocity is a continuous quantity.  This means, by the intermediate value theorem, ift it attains two different values, then it must attain every value inbetween.  Thus if velocity is positive at one point (before hitting the spring) and negative at another point (some time after bouncing off the spring), then the velocity must be 0 at some point.
A minor caveat to this is "impulsive" events, such as bouncing off of a hard wall.  In those cases, velocity can be discontinuous.  However, we also recognize that is just an approximation: the velocity of the object is continuous, even in such a case, but the bounce happens so quickly that we approximate it with a discontinuous curve.  But a spring has no such hard impulsive behavior.  In the cases you are interested in, velocity is continuous, so it always reaches zero at some point if it goes from positive to negative.

When the object strikes the spring its direction is reversed. Reversing direction requires an instant where the object's velocity is exactly zero. An analogous situation is the vertical velocity of a projectile launched into the air. at the apogee where the object changes direction and comes back down the velocity is zero for an instant. It is possible for an object to momentarily have zero velocity while experiencing constant acceleration when changing direction.

But does it not go with a constant velocity as it's a smooth part?

Constant velocity implies there is no net force acting on the object. When it make contact with the spring, the spring applies a force to the object. Coming down the slop gravitational potential energy is converted to the kinetic energy of the the object. On contacting the spring the kinetic energy is converted to the potential energy stored in the spring. Once the object has stopped, this stored potential energy is released once again converted to the kinetic energy of the object as it is accelerated back in the opposite direction.
